# if $ \{ a_1 , a_2 , \cdots, a_{10} \} = \{ 1, 2, \cdots , 10 \} $ . Find the maximum value of $I= \sum_{n=1}^{10}(na_n ^2 - n^2 a_n ) $

Tags: inequality, discrete-optimization

Let $ \{ a_1 , a_2 , \cdots, a_{10} \} = \{ 1, 2, \cdots , 10 \} $ . Find the maximum value of
$$I= \sum_{n=1}^{10}(na_n ^2 - n^2 a_n ) $$

I try: since $(a-b)^3=a^3-3a^2b+3ab^2-b^3$,and $\sum_{n=1}^{10}n^3=\sum_{n=1}^{10}a^3_{n}$so we have
$$3I=\sum_{n=1}^{10}(3na_{n}^2-3n^2a_{n})=\sum_{n=1}^{10}(n-a_{n})^3$$
take $b_{n}=n-a_{n}$,and we need to maxumize $\sum_{n=1}^{10}b^3_{n}$ with the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{10}b_{i}=0$ and $-9\le b_{i}\le 9$,and I can't,somedays ago,it is  said can use the  Karamata inequality to found it,and to day said the reslut is $336$,But I consider sometimes,can find it,Thank you for your help

Comment: There are only $10!$ arrangements! It's completely inelegant, but your device almost certainly has enough computing power to find the optimal arrangement within seconds. I'd highly recommend using `itertools` with python.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A049031.

Comment: @MartinR wow, it seems everything is on oeis at this point

Comment: By Holder's Inequality : $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{10} b_{n}^3 \leq \left ( \sum_{n=1}^{10} b_{n} \right )^3 . $ Is it ? Or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{n,v}$ indicate whether $a_n=v$.  The problem is to maximize
$$I = \sum_{n=1}^{10} (n a_n^2 - n^2 a_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{10} \sum_{v=1}^{10} (n v^2 - n^2 v) x_{n,v}$$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_v x_{n,v} &= 1 &&\text{for all $n$} \tag1 \\
\sum_n x_{n,v} &= 1 &&\text{for all $v$} \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ assigns exactly one value $v$ to each $a_n$.
Constraint $(2)$ assigns exactly one $a_n$ for each value $v$.

An optimal solution, with objective value $336$, turns out to be
$$x_{1,4}=x_{2,5}=x_{3,6}=x_{4,7}=x_{5,8}=x_{6,9}=x_{7,10}=x_{8,3}=x_{9,2}=x_{10,1}=1,$$ with all other $x_{n,v}=0$, and this solution corresponds to
$a=(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,3,2,1)$.

The linear programming upper bound is also $336$, and the dual variables provide a certificate of optimality.

Duals for the lower bound $x_{n,v} \ge 0$:
\begin{matrix}
n \backslash v &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10 \\ 
\hline
1 &-84 &-28 &0 &0 &-6 &-20 &-44 &-80 &-130 &-196 \\
2 &-90 &-34 &-4 &0 &0 &-6 &-20 &-44 &-80 &-130 \\
3 &-94 &-40 &-10 &-4 &0 &0 &-6 &-20 &-44 &-80 \\
4 &-94 &-44 &-16 &-10 &-4 &0 &0 &-6 &-20 &-44 \\
5 &-88 &-44 &-20 &-16 &-10 &-4 &0 &0 &-6 &-20 \\
6 &-74 &-38 &-20 &-20 &-16 &-10 &-4 &0 &0 &-6 \\
7 &-50 &-24 &-14 &-20 &-20 &-16 &-10 &-4 &0 &0 \\
8 &-14 &0 &0 &-14 &-20 &-20 &-16 &-10 &-4 &0 \\
9 &0 &0 &-12 &-36 &-50 &-56 &-56 &-52 &-46 &-40 \\ 
10 &0 &-16 &-42 &-78 &-102 &-116 &-122 &-122 &-118 &-112 \\
\end{matrix}
Duals for constraint $(1)$:
$$(50, 54, 54, 48, 34, 10, -26, -76, -106, -124)$$
Duals for constraint $(2)$:
$$(34, -20, -44, -38, -24, 0, 36, 86, 152, 236)$$
Multiplying the corresponding constraints by these dual multipliers and adding them up yields $I \le 336$, as claimed.

Answer (score 2):

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Notation.}}$

Denote 
\begin{cases}
\overrightarrow A = (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_{10})\\
\overrightarrow E = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),\\
R^{[k]}_z\left(\overrightarrow A\right) = (a_{z+1},a_{z+2},\dots,a_{k},a_1,a_2,\dots a_z,a_{k+1},a_{k+2},\dots,a_{10})\\
R\underbrace{_{z,y,\dots,f}}_l\left(\overrightarrow A\right) 
= \underbrace{R^{[11-l]}_f\left(\dots R^{[9]}_y\left(\dots R^{[10]}_z\left(\overrightarrow A\right)\right)\right)}_{l},\tag1
\end{cases}
where
$\quad z\in \{0,1,\dots,k\},\quad k\in \{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\},\quad l\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\},$

$\quad R^{[k]}_z\left(\overrightarrow A\right)$ is the left cyclic shift of the first $k$ components of $\overrightarrow A$ to $z$ positions,

$\quad R\underbrace{_{z,y,\dots,f}}_l\left(\overrightarrow A\right)$ is the superposition
of such shifts with the decreasing quantity of permutated components.

The first cyclic shift allows to set the value of $a_{10},$ the second cyclic shift - to set the value of $a_9,$ and so on.
For example,
\begin{cases}
R_1\left(\overrightarrow E\right) = (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1),\\
R_{1,1}\left(\overrightarrow E\right) = (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,1),\\
R_2\left(\overrightarrow E\right) = (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2),\dots
\end{cases}
Therefore, any vector $\overrightarrow A$ belongs to the set of superpositions $(2)$ of the cyclic shifts in the form of 
$$\left\{R_{\large z^\,_{10},z^\,_9,\dots,z^\,_2}\left(\overrightarrow E\right),\quad\text{where}\quad z_k\in\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}\right\}.$$

In the further, will be used short notation
$$\vec E_{\large z^\,_{10},z^\,_9,\dots,z^\,_2} 
 = R_{\large z^\,_{10},z^\,_9,\dots,z^\,_2}\left(\overrightarrow E\right),\quad
I_{\large z^\,_{10},z^\,_9,\dots,z^\,_2} 
 = I\left(\vec E_{\large z^\,_{10},z^\,_9,\dots,z^\,_2}\right).\tag2$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{The task standing.}}$

The goal function can be presented in the form of
$$I\left(\overrightarrow A\right) = \frac13\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10} n^3 - \frac13\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10} a_n^3 - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{10} n^2a_n +\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10} na_n^2 = \frac13\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10}(n-a_n)^3,\tag3$$
(see also OP).

Then the permutation of the pair $(a_k,a_{k+1})$ of neighbour elements leads to the difference 
\begin{align}
&3\Delta I = (k-a_k)^3 + (k+1-a_{k+1})^3 - (k-a_{k+1})^3 - (k+1-a_k)^3 \\
&= (a_{k+1}-a_k)\Big((k-a_k)^2+(k-a_k)(k-a_{k+1})+(k-a_{k+1})^2\Big)\\
&+(a_k-a_{k+1})\Big((k+1-a_k)^2+(k+1-a_k)(k+1-a_{k+1})+(k+1-a_{k+1})^2\Big)\\
&=3(a_{k+1}-a_k)\Big(k^2-ka_k-ka_{k+1} - (k+1)^2+(k+1)a_k+(k+1)a_{k+1}\Big)\\
&=3(a_{k+1}-a_k)(a_k+a_{k+1}-2k-1),
\end{align}

which should be positive for any pair of the solution's neighbour components.
This leads to constraint to the neighbour components of solution $\overrightarrow A$ in the form of

\begin{cases}
a_{k+1} > a_{k},\quad\text{if}\quad a_k+a_{k+1} > 2k+1\\
a_{k+1} < a_{k},\quad\text{if}\quad a_k+a_{k+1} < 2k+1.\tag4
\end{cases}

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Searching.}}$

The obtained task is a discrete optimization task. 
Should be maximized $I_{\large z^\,_{10},z^\,_9,\dots,z^\,_2},$ taking in account $(3)-(4).$

The goal function assumed unimodal.

The first cyclic shift leads to the vector
$$\vec E_z = (z+1,z+2,\dots,10,1,2,\dots z),\tag{5}$$
wherein from $(4)$ should $z<2.$

Then the single possible solution under constraints $(4)$ is $\vec E_1.$

Similarly, for dimensions $l\le5$ the set of the possible solutions is 
$$\{\vec E_1,\vec E_{1,1},\vec E_{1,1,1},\vec E_{1,1,1,1},\vec E_{1,1,1,1,1}\},$$

wherein
$$E\underbrace{_{1,1,\dots,1}}_l = (l+1,l+2,\dots,10,l,l-1,\dots,1),$$

$$3I\underbrace{_{1,1,\dots,1}}_l 
= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{10-l}(-l)^3 + \sum_{k=11-l}^{10}(2k-11)^3
= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{10-l}(-l)^3 + \sum_{k=1}^l (11-2k)^3,$$
$$I\underbrace{_{1,1,\dots,1}}_l = \frac13 l(9-l)(10-l)(11-l),\tag6$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}I_1 \\ I_{1,1} \\ I_{1,1,1} \\ I_{1,1,1,1} \\ I_{1,1,1,1,1}\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix} 240 \\ 336 \\ 336 \\ 280 \\ 200 \end{pmatrix}\tag7.$$

Therefore, maximum of the issue sum is

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{I_{\max}=336}}$ at $\color{green}{\mathbf{\overrightarrow A = (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,1)}}$ or 
$\color{green}{\mathbf{\overrightarrow A = (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,3,2,1)}}.$

Answer (score 1):

Here are some heuristic thoughts.

**A generalisation:**

We set $N=10$ and consider the generalisation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^N\left(na_n^2-n^2a_n\right)\qquad\to\qquad \max}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We computationally calculate the maximum of the sum in (1) for small values of $N=2,3,...,8$ and obtain
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|r|l}
N&\max&(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N)\\
\hline
2&0&(1,2)\\
&0&(2,\color{blue}{1})\\
3&2&(2,3,\color{blue}{1})\\
4&8&(2,3,4,\color{blue}{1})\\
5&20&(2,3,4,5,\color{blue}{1})\\
6&40&(2,3,4,5,6,\color{blue}{1})\\
&40&(3,4,5,6,\color{blue}{2,1})\\
7&80&(3,4,5,6,7,\color{blue}{2,1})\\
8&140&(3,4,5,6,7,8,\color{blue}{2,1})
\end{array}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

Table (2) clearly shows which kind of pattern we have to study. We start with a value $1\leq k\leq N-1$ and the sequence which produces a maximum is one or more of
\begin{align*}
\left(k+1,\ldots,N,\color{blue}{k,k-1,\ldots,1}\right)\qquad\qquad k\in\{1,2,\ldots,N-1\}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

**Plausibility check:**

The expression (1)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^N\left(na_n^2-n^2a_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^Nna_n^2-\sum_{n=1}^Nn^2a_n\qquad\to\qquad \max
\end{align*}
becomes a maximum if we can find pattern $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_N)$ so that one sum becomes as large as possible whereas the other sum becomes as small as possible (indicated by max/min with tilde notation).
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^Nna_n^2&\qquad\to\qquad\widetilde{\max}\\
\sum_{n=1}^Nn^2a_n&\qquad\to\qquad\widetilde{\min}
\end{align*}

> This approach is plausible, since
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{llll}
> (1,2,\ldots,N)&\to &\sum_{n=1}^N n a_n^2=\sum_{n=1}^Nn^3&\to\max\\
> \\
> (N,N-1,\ldots,1)&\to &\sum_{n=1}^N n a_n^2=\sum_{n=1}^Nn(N+1-n)^2&\to\min\\
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}
> are maximum and minimum values and cyclic shift of the permutation *decreases* the value of the first sum and *increases* the value of the second sum.

**Conclusion:**

It is sufficient to consider the $N-1$ permutations
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(k+1,k+2,\ldots,N,k,k-1,\ldots,1\right)\qquad\qquad k\in\{1,2,\ldots,N-1\}}
\end{align*}
which maximize the sum
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^N}\color{blue}{\left(na_n^2-n^2a_n\right)}\\
 &\ \ =\sum_{n=1}^{N-k}\left(n(n+k)^2-n^2(n+k)\right)\\
&\quad+\sum_{n=1}^k\left((N-k+n)(k+1-n)^2-(N-k+n)^2(k+1-n)\right)\\
&\ \;\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{3}k\left(N\left(N^2-1\right)-k\left(3N^2-1\right)+3k^2N-k^3\right)}\tag{4}\\
&\qquad\qquad\color{blue}{\to \max}
\end{align*}

> We finally find for $N=10$ using formula (4)
> \begin{align*}
> \begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrrr}
> k&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\
> \sum&240&\color{blue}{336}&\color{blue}{336}&280&200&120&56&16&0
> \end{array}
> \end{align*}
> two solutions $k=2,3$ providing a maximum:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,1)}\quad\to\quad\sum_{n=1}^{10}\left(na_n^2-n^2a_n\right)=\color{blue}{336}\\
> \color{blue}{(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,3,2,1)}\quad\to\quad\sum_{n=1}^{10}\left(na_n^2-n^2a_n\right)=\color{blue}{336}
> \end{align*}